# Webview Behaviour Changes API 28 on lower api devices

Tags: android, webview, android-networking, android-9.0-pie

The configuration of my app is like this:
targetSdk 28
minsdk24
compileSdk 28

When I try to load an ad with targetSDK 28, it does not load, unlike the situation when the targetSDK is 27, in which the ad loads successfully in my device which has API 27.

I've read through behaviour changes in WebView in API 28 from [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28).

Web-based data directories separated by process in API 28, and you should use WebView.setDataDirectorySuffix() before initializing WebView everytime, but obviously my device can not use this method since it is API 27, also, that might not be the problem since my app does not crash both in device with API 27 and emulator with API 28.

Normally if that was the  error should have caused a crash. And, if that's the problem, which can only be solved by the setDataDirectorySuffix() method which exists in API 28 and not in the APIs of earlier devices, would there be any way to solve this without getting NoSuchMethodError exception?

Also in API 28 cleartextTrafficPermitted() automatically returns false, I've created and set a [Network Security Configuration](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config) in my app for may domain, but it does not effect the situation also.

Only temporary solution I have right now to set targetSDK version to 27, but I am confused about what causes this problem and what to do, any help would be appreciated.

I've also tested this with an API28 emulator and still got the same problem even though I've been able to use setDataDirectorySuffix() method, but I may have defined the directory wrong.

Comment: And your ad provider is?